# c64 copy chars to sprite issue

Tags: commodore-64, assembly, sprite

How to do correct copying char to sprite ?
Lets say 1st char is at $2000 second is at $2008 and copying to sprite at $2480.
And with this we can copy 1 char to top left position of 1st sprite. But what if we add more chars or any from 0 to 255. How we will solve that regarding 2 sprites in left sideborders and two in right sideborders? Lets say with 30 chars which occupy 6 chars in 5 rows (so total 30 chars; assuming Y - rows X - columns)
We can copy 3 x 2 chars to two left sprites but what about 3rd row char (21 is not divisible with 8).
This routine copy 1 char to 1st sprite. How to copy 30 chars (6 chars in 5 rows) to 2 sprites which data are 1st $2480 2nd 24C0?

```
                    ldy #$00
               char lda $2000,y
                    sta $2480,x
                    inx
                    inx
                    inx
                    iny
                    cpy #$08
                    bne char
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Or at least, what is the routine supposed to do, so one could guess were it diverts?

Comment: It is a debugging question. It is rare here, but it is imho clear.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Could you [edit] the question to clarify it for the rest of us please, if you understand it?

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Well, I have no problem with debugging questions - even with bad written/documented code like here. Still, from reading above, I have no idea what it is about. What isa LogoMap, a sideboarder(s?) or even what 'math' is to be done. If it's clear to you, could you please try to explain it?

Comment: @Raffzahn Not clear. You are right. If the op disappears, then the question is at least unclear. Sad, I would be so happy to debug 6502 asm after so many decades again.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Same here. I love the '02, my favourite 8 bit (x86 being 16 and /370 being 32). So far I have only a bunch of wild guessing what this is about. For example if this is about reordering bytes to form some scrolling bitmap, then the shifting code needs to be within the loop - but then again, maybe it's something complete different, as the shifting doesn't make much sense either. The question needs a clear write up what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Hmm, thinking of it, this might be the very problem the OP has. He may not have written down first (in whatever way) what the task is and how it's performed. Usually this clears 95% of all design issues (the remaining 5% are when one realizes that the chosen solution isn't possible with a given CPU), leaving only typos to be searched later.

Comment: @Raffzahn C64 demos put sometimes characters into sprites. This could make funny effects looking impossible on the first spot (for example: you subtitute a character with a space, and simultaneously move it to a sprite. Then moving the sprite...)

Comment: Yeap demo effect showing sprites in sideborders. We can only put there sprites. But we can copy chars there (which is part of logo) so we can make looks like one big logo moving into sb to the left and then to the right for instance.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Well, you should get a TI99/4, as there chars and sprites are essentially the same anyway :)

Comment: Little tricky because the way chars and sprites are alligned.

Comment: @simun9 This still doesn't explain what you intend to do and what is to be done. The new description makes even less sense, and I'm doing 6502 since a bit more than 42 years. Please do simply explain what it should do and what are the steps to be taken - after all, if this is just about copying then all of the above is way over the edge. Likewhat is that shifting about and so on. Please write a simple list what you want to do.

Comment: For some reason cant put first part of the code to get complete pic.

Comment: @simun9 No idea what _"cant put first part of the code to get complete pic"_ is supposed to mean. I'd strongly suggest you write first down in clear detail, what the task is to be done.

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do here but you should think about the question "what is the value in `X` when you do the first `sta`?

Comment: Still not really sure, but now it seams like you _might_ want (among others) to move more than one character into a single sprite, so I modified my second reply. ...  Somehow this turns into a workshop about characters in sprites.

Comment: You can not copy 30 chars to 3 sprintes. Size of the sprites is 24x21 pixel, characters is 8x8, meaning that you can copy only 27 chars if you allow that the last line will lose its bottom 3 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a straight up copy, then what about reading the char's bitmap first, and then writing it to the sprite?

```
       ldy #$07
cpch:  lda (chptr),y
       pha
       dey
       bpl cpch

       ldy #$17
       ldx #$07
cpspr: pla
       sta (sprptr),y
       dey
       dey
       dey
       dex
       bpl cpspr
```

Something like that?

Comment: BTW, you could shave of the first and last :)

Comment: @Raffzahn what do you mean

Comment: Well, the first character can be transfered straight from chptr to sprptr without pushing while the last can be kept in A between both loops, so again saving an expensive PHA/PLA combination. But that was just a sidenote when thinking about the way you move it.

Comment: @Raffzahn That makes sense. It's a perfect optimisation for OP, who is a C64 democoder, to attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I still have no idea what the question is really about. So what follows is a wild guess from what the OP posted in question, edits and comments as well as what I think he could be about:

**Blowing Up an 8x8 Char Into a 24x21 Sprite**

*[I have no idea if this is right, but I can't believe it's just about copying, as that would be way too simple]*

A character is stored within the character generator as a sequence of 8 bytes each holding a line with bits set for each pixel to be set, high to low and left to right. Example

```
00011000 (18) ->    **   
00111100 (3C) ->   ****  
01100110 (66) ->  **  **
01111110 (7E) ->  ******
01100110 (66) ->  **  **
01100110 (66) ->  **  **
00000000 (00) ->
```

To turn this into a sprite, each bit needs to be tripled within a line - and similarly, each line needs to be tripled (*1), as sprites are simply 3 bytes per line and 21 lines.

```
00000000 01111110 00000000 (00 7E 00) ->          ******   
00000000 01111110 00000000 (00 7E 00) ->          ******   
00000000 01111110 00000000 (00 7E 00) ->          ******   
00000011 11111111 11000000 (03 FF C0) ->       ************  
00000011 11111111 11000000 (03 FF C0) ->       ************  
00000011 11111111 11000000 (03 FF C0) ->       ************  
00011111 10000001 11111000 (1F 81 F8) ->    ******      ******
00011111 10000001 11111000 (1F 81 F8) ->    ******      ******
00011111 10000001 11111000 (1F 81 F8) ->    ******      ******
00011111 11111111 11111000 (1F FF F8) ->    ******************
00011111 11111111 11111000 (1F FF F8) ->    ******************
00011111 11111111 11111000 (1F FF F8) ->    ******************
00011111 10000001 11111000 (1F 81 F8) ->    ******      ******
00011111 10000001 11111000 (1F 81 F8) ->    ******      ******
00011111 10000001 11111000 (1F 81 F8) ->    ******      ******
00011111 10000001 11111000 (1F 81 F8) ->    ******      ******
00011111 10000001 11111000 (1F 81 F8) ->    ******      ******
00011111 10000001 11111000 (1F 81 F8) ->    ******      ******
[No line 22..24]
```

The following routine is a straight implementation without much in the way of tricks to get the job done. There might be some optimization possible, but I'd prefer to get it working first, before playing with alternative/more compact solutions.

Also, unlike the code posed with the question, this is made with pointers, keeping it as independent from any environment as possible (and free of self modifying code, so ROMable). So again, later optimizations may change this and save some code ... but as before I'd put that way at the end of all development. Having independent subroutines help a lot to minimize development issues.

It's not necessarily made for the shortest possible code, but execution time should be fairly good.

```
; Generic subroutine to convert a character definition
; (a bitmap stored in 8 consecutive bytes) into a sprite
; of 24x21 pixel

; Called at
;  convert

; In:
;  chrptr, word, holding address of the character definition, will be modified
;  sptr, word, holding the address of a 63 byte area to be filled with sprite data

; Out:
;  63 bytes of sprite data processed from character data stored beginning at sptr
;  chrptr pointing to the last line (not converted) of the character.

; In/Out
chrptr  DW  0   ; A zp-pointer to an 8 byte character definition to be converted
sptr    DW  0   ; A zp-pointer to a 64 byte area to be filled with the expanded character

; Local variables
sptr1   DW  0   ; Support pointer (zp) to the second line (copy of first+3)
sptr2   DW  0   ; Support pointer (zp) to the third line (copy of first+6)
temp    DB  0   ; temporary value for conversion

; Entry
convert:

;Setup
        LDA  sptr        ; prepare the pointers to save later on
        LDX  sptr+1
        CLC
        ADC  #3
        BCC  nopage1
        INX
nopage1:
        STA  sptr1       ; Pointer for second sprite line
        STX  sptr1+1
        CLC
        ADC  #3
        BCC  nopage1
        INX
nopge2:
        STA  sptr2       ; Pointer for third sprite line
        STX  sptr2+1

        LDY  #0          ; Offset within the character definition
        LDX  #7          ; 7 lines to be converted (no room for the 8th

;Conversion loop
loop:
        LDA  chrptr      ; Load a character line and bring it into tmp
        ROL  A           ; But let's extract the first bit first  - saves 3 cycles and a byte :))
        STA  temp
        LDA  #0          ; Clear A
        BCC  J1A         ; Was the top bit set ? 
        LDA  #%11100000  ; Yes -> set the first 3 bits of the sprite
J1A:
        ROL  temp        ; Check second bit
        BCC  J1B         ; Was it set ?
        ORA  #%00011100  ; Yes -> set the second 3 bits of the sprite
J1B:
        ROL  temp        ; Check third bit
        BCC  J1C         ; Was it set?
        ORA  #%00000011  ; Yes -> set the third 3 bits of the sprite ... ups, there are only two left in this byte
J1C:
        STA  (sptr),Y    ; Store first byte of first line
        STA  (sptr1),Y   ; Store first byte of second line
        STA  (sptr2),Y   ; Store first byte of third line

        INY              ; Next byte of the sprite
        LDA  #0          ; Clear A
        ROR              ; Bring the remaining bit into the second sprite byte

        ROL  temp        ; Check bit 4
        BCC  J2A         ; Was it set?
        ORA  #%01110000  ; Yes -> set the 4th 3 bits of the sprite 
J2A:
        ROL  temp        ; Check bit 5
        BCC  J2B         ; Was it set?
        ORA  #%00001110  ; Yes -> set the 5th 3 bits of the sprite 
J2B:
        ROL  temp        ; Check bit 6
        BCC  J2C         ; Was it set?
        ORA  #%00000001  ; Yes -> set the 6th 3 bits of the sprite - again wraping into the next byte
J2C:
        STA  (sptr),Y    ; Store second byte of first line
        STA  (sptr1),Y   ; Store second byte of second line
        STA  (sptr2),Y   ; Store second byte of third line
 
        INY              ; Next byte of the sprite
        LDA  #0          ; Clear A
        BCC  J3A         ; Was bit 6 set?
        ORA  #%11000000  ; Yes -> set the remaining bits of the 6th group
J3A:
        BIT  temp        ; Check bit 7 (Now using BIT to save 2 cycles)
        BPL  J3B         ; Was it set?
        ORA  #%00111000  ; Yes -> set the 7th 3 bits of the sprite 
J3B:
        BIT  temp        ; Check bit 8 (Now using BIT to save 2 cycles)
        BVC  J3C         ; Was it set?
        ORA  #%00000111  ; Yes -> set the 8th 3 bits of the sprite 
J3C:
        STA  (sptr),Y    ; Store third byte of first line
        STA  (sptr1),Y   ; Store third byte of second line
        STA  (sptr2),Y   ; Store third byte of third line

        DEX                    ; All 7 done?
        BEQ  end               ; Yes -> end

; Adjust pointer(s)

; Y needs to skip three lines/9 bytes (which are already filled) minus the two INY that already happened. Doing it via A saves 2 bytes and 4 cycles. Also, writing so many INY just adds a chance of a miscount.
        TYA
        CLC
        ADC  #7                ; 9-2
        TAY

; select next line in character
        INC  chrptr            ; Select next line of character
        BNE  loop              ; Next round if no page carry
        INC  chrptr+1          ; handle page carry
        BNE  loop              ; next round (will fail if the character table wraps at $FFFF - not really likely)

end:
        RTS
```

Let's see if this is in any way related to the question :))

*[... thinking of it, there would also be a way for a table driven solution that may be shorter and faster ... though, not sure, as above is ~127 bytes, while the table base solution needs already 32 bytes of table... :)]*

---

*1 - Yes, I know, this doesn't end well, as there is no room for the lowest line.

Comment: A reasonable guess, so let's see if OP can use it

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative solution

With the last edit, it seems as if it could be not about blowing up a character, but filling 6 character definitions located in sequence into 6 sprites, again located in sequence. As before, it's just a guess due to the rather unclear wording.

A routine to copy one char into one sprite (pre cleaned) might look like this:

```
; Generic subroutine to convert a character definition
; (a bitmap stored in 8 consecutive bytes) into a sprite
; of 8x8 pixel

; Called at
;  convert

; In:
;  chrptr, word, holding address of char definition, will be modified
;                character data is assumed not to spread over a page boundry
;  sprptr, word, holding the address of a 63 byte area to be filled with sprite data
;                sprite area is assumed not to spread over a page boundary
;                sprite area is assumed not to be zeroed out

; Out:
;  sprite data processed from character data stored beginning at sprptr
;  chrptr pointing after the last line of the character.


chrptr  DW   0
sprptr  DW   0

convert:

;Setup
        LDY  #0          ; Sprite index
        LDX  #0
moveit:                  ; well, move it!
        LDA  (chrptr,X)  ; Same as (chrptr), but that's only available on a 65C02
        STA  (sprptr),Y 

        CPY  #3*7        ; Last line done?
        BEQ  done        ; Yes -> return
        INC  chrptr      ; Next character line
        INY              ; Next sprite line
        INY
        INY
        JMP  moveit      ; Move it :))

done:
        RTS
```

A routine calling the above for 6 consecutive character definitions into 6 consecutive sprites may look like this:

```
chrcnt  DB  0            ; Temporary counter, preferably in zeropage

entry:
        LDA #>charlist   ; Set pointer to list of character definitions
        STA chrptr
        LDA #<charlist
        STA chrptr+1

        LDA #>spritearea ; Set pointer to sprite area
        STA sprptr
        LDA #<spritearea
        STA sprptr+1

        LDA #6           ; Doing 6 chars
        STA chrcnt

cvtlp:
        JSR convert      ; Convert a char to sprite
        DEC chrcnt
        BEQ end          ; Last char -> exit
                         ; Character pointer is already advanced by convert
        LDA sprptr       ; Move pointer to next sprite
        CLC
        ADC #64          ; Length of a sprite entry
        STC sprptr
        BCC cvtlp        ; No carry -> Next round
        INC sprptr+1
        BCC cvtlp        ; Always -> Next round

end:
```

Of course there are many more variations possible, like

- using an ASCII string as input and getting the character bitmap from the character generator,

Which would simply require locating the character definition from its character code, and hand over that address as pointer.

- packing them in two sprites (row of 3 characters per sprite) if it's supposed to be a horizontal scrolling text

This can be done much like before, but after setting up the pointers we need to move them into the same sprite, offset by one:

```
        LDA #3           ; Doing 3 chars
        STA chrcnt

cvtlp:
        JSR convert      ; Convert a char to sprite
        DEC chrcnt
        BEQ end          ; Last char -> exit
                         ; Character pointer is already advanced by convert
        INC sprptr       ; Move pointer to next character position within sprite
        BCC cvtlp        ; Always -> Next round

end:
```

*[Is it obvious why I prefer routines that can be reused, over premature optimized code?]*

- packing them in three sprites (column of 2 characters per sprite) if it's supposed to be a vertical scrolling text

Like above, but after setting up the pointers simply inserting the two characters:

```
        JSR convert      ; Convert first char into sprite
        LDA sprptr       ; Advance sprite pointer within the sprite to the next row
        CLC
        ADC #8*3         ; Skip 8 rows of 3 bytes
        STC sprptr       ; Correction of high-byte is not needed as sprites
                         ; are always aligned to $40 boundaries
        JSR convert      ; Convert second char into sprite
```

- packing all 6 characters into a single sprite forming a two lines of 3 characters sprite

I guess, by now, the picture is clear: Rinse and repeat.

- ... and so on ...

---

**So, again, possibilities are endless with the unclear information given. There is no chance to give a definitive answer without a clear definition of the intended layout/usage.**